# Funcion de peleadores en javascript con do while

Tags: javascript, algoritmos

Estoy haciendo una funcion de 2 peleadores que se enfrentan y en base a su ataque y vida se declara un ganador... lo que sucede es que si la vida de ambos es negativa declaro el ganador a partir del que tiene menor vida, no por el primero en quedar con su vida negativa o igual 0(sucede en este ejemplo que pongo con mi funcion).. necesitaria poner condiciones dentro del do while o algo asi... Alguna recomendacion para mejorar el codigo tambien me ayudaria..Gracias

```js
function Fighter(name, health, damagePerAttack) {
    this.name = name;
    this.health = health;
    this.damagePerAttack = damagePerAttack;
    this.toString = function() { return this.name; }
}

function declareWinner(fighter1, fighter2, firstAttacker) {
let ganador ="El ganador es... ";
let intercambio = fighter1;

console.log('Inicia la batalla... \n');
(firstAttacker != fighter1.name) 
?  (fighter1= fighter2, fighter2 = intercambio, console.log(`El primer ataque es para... `+ fighter1.name))
: console.log(`La primer ataque es para... `+fighter1.name);

do{
    fighter2.health -= fighter1.damagePerAttack
    console.log(`${fighter1.name} lanza un ataque de ${fighter1.damagePerAttack}... La salud de ${fighter2.name} es: ${fighter2.health}`); 
    fighter1.health -= fighter2.damagePerAttack
    console.log(`${fighter2.name} lanza un ataque de ${fighter2.damagePerAttack}... La salud de ${fighter1.name} es: ${fighter1.health}`);
   
}while(fighter2.health >= 0 && fighter1.health >= 0)

(fighter1.health >0 & fighter1.health>fighter2.health) ? ganador+=fighter1.name : ganador+=fighter2.name

return ganador
}

console.log(declareWinner(new Fighter("Pikashu", 10, 2), new Fighter("Meow", 5, 4), 'Pikashu'));
```

Comment: Lo único que tendrías que hacer es comprobar con un `if` si el atacante tiene vida, `if(fighter1.health >= 0)` si es así, realizas la resta de los puntos de vida del luchador que recibe el golpe y lo sacas por consola. Como idea, te sugiero que añadas una estadística de velocidad (speed) para así declarar que luchador atacara primero y que no sea solo el que primero se defina. Ademas, no se muy bien para que quieres el programa, si es algún trabajo o algo pero las estadísticas se podrían genera automáticamente con números aleatorios para que cada pelea el resultado sea diferente.

Comment: Si tenias razon @x3k_js ... gracias,  pensaba que si lo hacia asi no se cumpliria la condicion de salida aun estoy siguiendo la logica pero me funciona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asi me quedo la funcion de los peleadores... aun se puede mejorar muchisimo

```js
function Fighter(name, health, damagePerAttack) {
    this.name = name;
    this.health = health;
    this.damagePerAttack = damagePerAttack;
    this.toString = function() { return this.name; }
}

function declareWinner(fighter1, fighter2, firstAttacker) {
    let ganador ="El ganador es... ";

    console.log('Inicia la batalla... \n');
    (firstAttacker != fighter1.name) 
    ?  ([fighter1, fighter2] = [fighter2, fighter1], console.log(`La primera sangre es para.. `+ fighter1.name))
    : console.log(`La primera sangres es para.. `+fighter1.name);

    do{
        if(fighter1.health>0){
            fighter2.health -= fighter1.damagePerAttack
            console.log(`${fighter1.name} lanza un ataque de ${fighter1.damagePerAttack}... La salud de ${fighter2.name} es: ${fighter2.health}`);
        }
        if(fighter2.health>0){
            fighter1.health -= fighter2.damagePerAttack
            console.log(`${fighter2.name} lanza un ataque de ${fighter2.damagePerAttack}... La salud de ${fighter1.name} es: ${fighter1.health}`);
        }    
   } while(fighter2.health >= 0 && fighter1.health >= 0)

   (fighter1.health >0) ? ganador+=fighter1.name : ganador+=fighter2.name

   return ganador
}

console.log(declareWinner(new Fighter("Pikashu", 10, 2), new Fighter("Meow", 5, 4), 'Meow'));
```